# PHP Backend validation of a phone number

Tags: php, string, validation

**Hello and thank you for taking the time to look at my post.**

I am creating a sign-up where I am making a backend validation. Here I'm using strlen to check the length of a field. For the password it is for instance looking like the following:

```
if (strlen($password) < 8 || strlen($password) > 15) {
  $error_message = 'password+issue';
  header("Location: /signup/error/$error_message");
  exit();
}
```

This seemed to work. I was however later asked by an online teacher in regards to the validation of the phone number. Here I wrote the following (and was hit with a little criticism)

```
$phone = $_POST['phone'];

if (strlen($phone) !== 8) {
  $error_message = 'Phone+issue';
  header("Location: /signup/error/$error_message");
  exit();
}
```

I am however not entirely sure why. Is it because the phone number is considered as integers while the strlen only takes strings into consideration? I did not believe that was the case here.

**It shouldn't really matter** but here is the html attached to it

```
<div class="wrapInput">
<input class="input" name="phone" type="text" placeholder="phone" required>
</div>
```

**Also yes** I am aware that length can be controlled in the following way:

```
//Validate phone number
$regexNumber = '#^[1-9][0-9]{7}$#';
if (!preg_match($regexNumber, $phone)) {
  $error_message = 'Invalid+PhoneDetails';
  header("Location: /signup/error/$error_message");
  exit();
}
```

but I am looking to see if this could be done with strlen in particular.

**TL;DR**

I am looking for a way to backend validate the phone number in PHP with the use of strlen. Are there any issue with the way I've done it?

Comment: Did the tutor not explain why they criticised your work? Normally a tutor would explain why they considered that you had done something badly, or incorrectly. I personally can't see an issue with checking it using `strlen()` as long as you don't mind rejecting phone numbers that don't match that length - for example any phone number in the UK won't be eight digits in length.

Comment: `strlen()` will work fine for this, because PHP will automatically convert from int to string as needed. I'm not sure where you are located that your phone numbers are 8 digits, but I think your teacher's issue may be that people often enter phone numbers with punctuation like `123-456-7890` or `(123) 456-7890` and your test does not consider that possibility. <shrug> Just a guess.

Comment: Your phone validation is just "8 characters". Something like `pinkblue` is a valid phone number then.

Comment: Also, even if the phone number is only comprised of digits, always consider it to be a string. Various locales have phone numbers beginning with one or more zeroes, or might require `+` or other symbols. Also, you're _never_ going to do math on a phone number.